# mutate(across(contains("column" with additional modifications to each column after storing column names

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have some data which looks something like (using the `iris` data):

```
myData <- iris %>% 
  tibble() %>% 
  mutate(
    across(contains("Length"),  ~paste(., "k", sep = "")),
    across(contains("Width"), ~paste(., "M", sep = ""))
    ) %>% 
  setNames(c("column1", "column2", "column3", "column4", "Other"))
```

Which looks like:

```
   column1 column2 column3 column4 Other 
   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <fct> 
 1 5.1k    3.5M    1.4k    0.2M    setosa
 2 4.9k    3M      1.4k    0.2M    setosa
 3 4.7k    3.2M    1.3k    0.2M    setosa
 4 4.6k    3.1M    1.5k    0.2M    setosa
 5 5k      3.6M    1.4k    0.2M    setosa
```

So it has some numbers along with `k` and `M`. (The `k` and `M` are not always the same in each column, i.e. one column could contain both `k` and `M` - which are thousands and millions respectively)

I want to extract all of the `k`'s and `M`'s so I use the following:

```
myData %>% 
  mutate(
    across(contains("column"),  ~str_sub(., -1), .names = "k_or_m_{.col}")
  )
```

Which gives:

```
   column1 column2 column3 column4 Other  k_or_m_column1 k_or_m_column2 k_or_m_column3 k_or_m_column4
   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <fct>  <chr>          <chr>          <chr>          <chr>         
 1 5.1k    3.5M    1.4k    0.2M    setosa k              M              k              M             
 2 4.9k    3M      1.4k    0.2M    setosa k              M              k              M             
 3 4.7k    3.2M    1.3k    0.2M    setosa k              M              k              M             
 4 4.6k    3.1M    1.5k    0.2M    setosa k              M              k              M
```

Which is what I want, but I would also like to make additional computations on the first 4 columns. I could add into the code `across(starts_with("column"), ~str_remove_all(., "k|M"))` or:

```
myData %>% 
  mutate(
    across(contains("column"),  ~str_sub(., -1), .names = "k_or_m_{.col}"),
    across(starts_with("column"), ~str_remove_all(., "k|M"))
    )
```

Which does solve the problem here. However in my actual data I have some `k` and `M`'s which get removed when applying the `starts_with` function.

For example (where I add a column `columnM` which contains some text with the character `M`):

```
   column1 column2 column3 column4 Other  columnM k_or_m_column1 k_or_m_column2 k_or_m_column3 k_or_m_column4 k_or_m_columnM
   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <fct>  <chr>   <chr>          <chr>          <chr>          <chr>          <chr>         
 1 5.1k    3.5M    1.4k    0.2M    setosa columnM k              M              k              M              M             
 2 4.9k    3M      1.4k    0.2M    setosa columnM k              M              k              M              M             
 3 4.7k    3.2M    1.3k    0.2M    setosa columnM k              M              k              M              M             
 4 4.6k    3.1M    1.5k    0.2M    setosa columnM k              M              k              M              M
```

I only want to remove the `k` or `M` on the first 4 columns.

```
myData %>% 
  add_column('columnM') %>% 
  rename(columnM = `"columnM"`) %>% 
  mutate(
    across(contains("column"),  ~str_sub(., -1), .names = "k_or_m_{.col}"),
    across(starts_with("column"), ~str_remove_all(., "k|M"))
    )
```

The `M` in `columnM` gets removed since the column `starts_with` the word `column`. i.e. as below.

```
   column1 column2 column3 column4 Other  columnM k_or_m_column1 k_or_m_column2 k_or_m_column3 k_or_m_column4 k_or_m_columnM
   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <fct>  <chr>   <chr>          <chr>          <chr>          <chr>          <chr>         
 1 5.1     3.5     1.4     0.2     setosa column  k              M              k              M              M             
 2 4.9     3       1.4     0.2     setosa column  k              M              k              M              M             
 3 4.7     3.2     1.3     0.2     setosa column  k              M              k              M              M
```

So my question is, how can I apply something like `[[cur_column()]]` to use `str_remove_all()`? i.e. I added this line but it does not work `mutate(across(contains("column")), ~ str_remove_all([[cur_column()]], "k|M"))`

Comment: I don't understand why `cur_column()` would help you. If the name or position of the columns is fixed, can't you use `across(1:4, ~str_remove_all(.x, "k|M"))`? Of course that's supposing it's always the first 4 columns.

Comment: Or you can use `matches("^column[0-9]+$")` to select the column name with a regex, so that you're not sensitive to the position.

Answer (score 1):

As user Alexlok said, this is quite a strange question. Ideally, you would never have columns with such similar names containing such similar values (use descriptive names!! Not just "Column[x]"!)

That said, if you do end up in this position, there are a few things you can do:

1. As Alexlok described, use `matches("^column[0-9]+$")` to only match columns which start with column, then a number:

```
myData %>% 
  mutate(columnM = "columnM", across(matches("^column[0-9]+$"), ~ as.numeric(str_replace(., "[kM]$", ""))))

column1 column2 column3 column4 Other  columnM k_or_m_column1 k_or_m_column2
     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <fct>  <chr>   <chr>          <chr>         
 1     5.1     3.5     1.4     0.2 setosa columnM k              M             
 2     4.9     3       1.4     0.2 setosa columnM k              M             
 3     4.7     3.2     1.3     0.2 setosa columnM k              M             
 4     4.6     3.1     1.5     0.2 setosa columnM k              M             
 5     5       3.6     1.4     0.2 setosa columnM k              M             
 6     5.4     3.9     1.7     0.4 setosa columnM k              M             
 7     4.6     3.4     1.4     0.3 setosa columnM k              M             
 8     5       3.4     1.5     0.2 setosa columnM k              M             
 9     4.4     2.9     1.4     0.2 setosa columnM k              M             
10     4.9     3.1     1.5     0.1 setosa columnM k              M
```

Another, arguably better alternative, is not storing the "k" or "M" in another column, because you're essentially representing the split one number into two halves, and put it in two columns, which is the opposite of what tidy data recommends. Much better to just replace the `k`s with `000` and the `M`s with `000000`:

```
myData %>%
  mutate(
    across(
      starts_with("column"),
      ~ ifelse(
          str_detect(., "k$"),
          as.numeric(str_remove(., "k")) * 1000,
          as.numeric(str_remove(., "M")) * 1000000
        )
    )
  )

   column1 column2 column3 column4 Other 
     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <fct> 
 1    5100 3500000    1400  200000 setosa
 2    4900 3000000    1400  200000 setosa
 3    4700 3200000    1300  200000 setosa
 4    4600 3100000    1500  200000 setosa
 5    5000 3600000    1400  200000 setosa
 6    5400 3900000    1700  400000 setosa
 7    4600 3400000    1400  300000 setosa
 8    5000 3400000    1500  200000 setosa
 9    4400 2900000    1400  200000 setosa
10    4900 3100000    1500  100000 setosa
```